# App Engine Application ID for custom ssl setup

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, cname

I have one domain(abc.com). I added cname as login then url becomes as login.abc.com.
I want to add ssl for custom url. I went to admin console security->ssl for customs domain.
There i need to add "App Engine Application ID", I am trying to add app engine application id, but it is not working. It is redirecting to admin console of that domain. 
Billing is already enabled. 
I am not getting what is going wrong here.
can anyone guide me ? is any steps i missed out..?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use SSL for custom domains, you need to follow these instructions:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl